# Firebase onDataChange create new view in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database, android-constraintlayout

I'm new to Android Development and Firebase. I'm looking for an easy way to do the following simple job:

1. Retrieve data from Firebase database
2. Create a list of checkbox from the data

Here is my code:

```
protected void AttachFirebaseListner(){
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("data");
    ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int i = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String guid = child.getKey();
                DataObjects.Box box = child.getValue(DataObjects.Box.class);
                CreateCheckBox(i,guid,box);
                i++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
}
```

and the function to create the check box:

```
protected void CreateCheckBox(int seq, String guid, DataObjects.Box box){
    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
    int currentID = 100+seq;
    int previousID = 100+(seq-1);

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.leftToLeft = PARENT_ID;
    if (seq == 0) { //first
        layoutParams.topToTop = PARENT_ID;
    }
    else {
        layoutParams.topToBottom = previousID;
    }

    CheckBox chkBox= new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
    chkBox.setId(currentID);
    chkBox.setTag(guid);
    chkBox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    chkBox.setText(box.name);

    layout.addView(chkBox);

    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    set.clone(layout);
    if (seq == 0) { //first
        set.connect(chkBox.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
    }
    else {
        set.connect(chkBox.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, previousID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    }
    set.applyTo(layout);
}
```

However, it seems that the onDataChange method is Asynchronous therefore the checkboxes are not populated.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks
CL

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm doing it correctly, I end up adding a listview in the constraint layout, and used an custom array adapter to bind my data to the listview.

guide: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView